# Keep UI after emit state change Cubit Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

My Question: Can you keep built UI that was built by a state when another state is called?

Please correct me if I'm using the cubit pattern wrong. I have a unique example I'm trying to solve. I have the cubit set up and it's working as per documentation.

I have a screen where I have a horizontal list that is returned through cubit. Then based on the horizontal list returned if you click one of the items the cubit fetches a second list to display vertically underneath the horizontal list.

```
var _responseCategories = await _repository.postGetRootCategories();
      emit(ShowCategories(state, _responseCategories));
      var _responseCategoryItems = await _repository.postGetCategoryItems(_responseCategories[0].id);
      emit(ShowCategoriesItems(state, _responseCategoryItems));
```

The ui has a bloc builder and processes the two states but when the one state is changed the UI for the first built state is then not there I understand why this happens but is there a way to stop it until I emit the state again. The UI decodes the states in a builder as follows:

```
return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                if (state is ShowCategories) buildCategories(context, state),
                state is ShowCategoriesItems
                    ? Expanded(child: buildMenuItems(context, state))
                    : SizedBox.shrink(), //getMenuList(_activeSelection)),
             
              ],
            );
```

If I'm using this wrong that's understandable I just want to know if there is a better solution to this to solve the problem as the category items are different per category and I don't need to fetch the categories every time the state changes.

The app is essentially a menu. The horizontal section is the categories of the menu 'I only need to load them once' and the vertical section is the items 'I need to load them when the user selects a category'. The items are different per category but the categories never change unless set by the server.

Comment: you can have the same property in both states so even a state changes you have access to desired values for building UI elements.

Comment: @Hamed Isn't it bad practice to duplicate information in multiple states. If I understood you correctly is there no better way to achieve my desired outcome.

Comment: There is no data duplication as we use reference object. We just provide information in another state.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a master-detail view and your detail state is just a superset of the master-no-detail state.

You could derive your detail state from the master state and add more information to it (master-list, adding selected, details-list to the derived class) or you could just go with one state for both (master-list, selected, details-list) where some things aren't set when nothing is selected yet.

If your details view is really complicated, you could also create a whole new BLoC for it, with it's own logic and builder in the widget tree, then you can have totally different states.

But states from the same BLoC, you cannot opt to only rebuild a part of the tree below the builder.

<sup>(well, technically you can do anything, but there is no point in working around a pattern. If it does not fit, use a different one. And I think you can easily make it fit as described above)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try some of the points you suggested @nvoigt